# how to download and save files to jenkins from another url?

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration, cicd, cloudbees

I have a python script running on cloudbees,
During the earlier iteration of the project when the code was running on the local machine, this python script used to download a .zip file from another host machine and used to store the zip file in a local folder from which the contents were read again by the script and posted onto a website.

Now, we are trying to move the script to cloudbees and although I could make a connection with the host machine, I could not download the file into the local folder for jenkins do not recognize a windows path, alternatively I was told that the downloaded zip file could be kept in the cloudbees/jenkins itself. Can someone suggest me how to do it? any useful links or libraries for the same?
This is the code I used to download file from a jenkins server into local machine, it runs perfectly when run from my local machine, but when run from cloudbees it throws error that it cannot recognise the path name_of_file_to_be_downloaded, I understand that it is because its a windows path name on a local machine. But how do I handle and keep the downloaded .zip file in cloudbees instance and later push it to artifactory?

```
jenkins_session = requests.Session()
jenkins_session.auth = (jenkins_auth_userid, jenkins_user_token)
retry = Retry(connect=10,backoff_factor=5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
jenkins_session.mount('http://', adapter)
jenkins_session.mount('https://', adapter)
req = jenkins_session.get(url)
print(req.status_code)
with open(name_of_file_to_be_downloaded, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(req.content)
    output.close
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. If the Python script is downloading the file why do you want Jenkins to do it? How do you download the file?

Comment: Hi the python script is running on jenkins and it downloads the file from another host, but it cannot keep it in my local machine becase I want everything to happen on cloud. Is there a way to download and keep the file in jenkins workspace temporarily ? because aftwrewards I will be pushing it to an artifactory from jenkins.

Comment: If the Python script downloads the file, Can't you just run the Python script on the Cloud? There are different ways to Download files, for example. Through an FTP, using HTTP, through SSH etc. So without knowing how you want to download it it's difficult to give an answer.

Comment: HI , I have edited the question, I use HTTP to download files